# Выборка по времени func.strftime SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Не получается отфильтровать данные по '%V'.

```
asd = User.query.get(1)
print(asd.created_at.strftime('%V'))
>>> 07
print('0' + str(int(datetime.now().isocalendar()[1])))
>>> 07

nnnn = User.query.filter(func.strftime('%V', User.created_at) == ('0' + str(datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]))).all()
print(nnnn)

>>> []
```

Для пущей уверенности, я сделал проверку:

```
if asd.created_at.strftime('%V') == ('0' + str(int(datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]))):
    print('yeah!')
```

на что получаю

```
>>> yeah!
```

> %V - The ISO 8601 week number of the current year (01 to 53), where
>   week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the current year,
>   and with Monday as the first day of the week
>
> %W - week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday
>   as the first day of the first week

Однако, при этом, если я заменяю '%V' на '%W', то результаты не меняются (при принте получаю 07 и 07 в обеих случаях, т.к. в этом году %V = %W), а выборка отдаёт нужный результат.

В чём может быть дело ?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На моей системе: `SELECT strftime('%V','now');` возвращает `None` (`SELECT strftime('%W','now')` возвращает `'07'`). На PostgreSQL можно попробовать: `session.query(User).filter(func.to_char(User.created_at, 'IW') == '07')`

Comment: в сторону: можно  `'%02d' % datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]`, чтобы автоматически ноль добавлять, если необходимо.

Comment: @jfs , на девелопменте использую sqllite3 (о чём сейчас жалею, в связи с отсутствием возможности дропнуть), а на продакшне postgres, по этому не смогу проверить.